# Type of anonymous identity function in Idris

Tags: identity, anonymous-function, type-inference, lambda-calculus, idris

When checking the type if `id` in Idris, we get what we would expect:

```
> :type id
id : a -> a
```

However, checking the lambda expression version throws a difficult error:

```
> :type \x => x
(input):Incomplete term \x => x
```

Why is this? If I use a function to coerce the context of `x` to a type, I get what I would expect:

```
> :type \x => x+1
\x => x + 1 : Integer -> Integer
```

Comment: Isn't this simply because Idris doesn't have type inference for functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type inference, in general, is undecidable for dependent types, see e.g. [the answers to this CS.SE question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12691/26856). In Idris, you can get away with not specifying types for some terms, but not all.

If you add your definition to an `.idr` file and try to load it, like

```
myId = \x => x
```

you will get the informative error message

> No type declaration for `Main.myId`

So let's see how far we need to go in giving it a type (the below is with Idris 0.10.2):

```
myId : _
myId = \x => x
```

> When checking right hand side of `myId` with expected type
>                `iType`
>
> Type mismatch between
>            `_ -> _` (Type of `\x => x`)
>    and
>            `iType` (Expected type)

OK, let's try a function type:

```
myId : _ -> _
myId = \x => x
```

> When checking right hand side of `myId` with expected type
>            `ty -> hole`
>
> Type mismatch between
>            `ty` (Type of `x`)  and
>            `hole` (Expected type)

I'll spare you subsequent steps, but basically `myId : {a : Type} -> a -> _` and `myId : {a : Type} -> _ -> a` both fail the same way, leaving us with

```
myId : {a : _} -> a -> a
myId = \x => x
```

So we had to specify the full type of `myId` except for the universe level of    the type variable `a`.

The final version of `myId`'s type signature can also be written as

```
myId : a -> a
myId = \x => x
```